# Do python single line comments have to obey indentation/whitespace rules?

Tags: python

If I have python code that requires indenting (`for`, `with`, function, etc), will a single line comment end potentially the context of the construct if I place it incorrectly? For example, presuming `step1`, `step2` and `step3` are functions already defined, will:

```
def myFunc():
    step1()
#   step2()
    step3()
```

(unintentionally) reduce the scope of `myFunc()` so that it only contains `step1`? If I only want to remove `step2` from the 3-step sequence, must I place the `#` at the same level of indentation as the statements within the scope of the construct? All the code I have seen so far suggests this is a requirement, but it might just be a coding habit.

Comment: As per [pep-8 block comments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#block-comments): "indented to the same level as that code". You should probably enable Anaconda -> pep8

Comment: Have you considered testing this?

Comment: Of course. But I would not have received the insights about PEP8 and other contributions below. And people like me would not have had the first (or second) clue to find that inside half an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it out:

```
def myFunc():
    print(1)
#   print(2)
    print(3)
myFunc()
```

which outputs:

```
1
3
```

So yeah, the answer is "Line comments don't need to match indentation". That said, [PEP8 really prefers that they do, just for readability](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#block-comments).

Answer (score 3):

Syntax-wise, blank lines are ignored. Blank lines include lines that have any amount of white space followed by a comment. 
https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#blank-lines
Indenting a comment the way you show in your example does not change the block of code included in your function.

Convention-wise, PEP8 calls for comments indented to the same indentation as code.

Comment: The 2.0 reference docs are a tad out of date; they apply here, but I'd never trust them to apply reliably to 2.7 code (which has changed in small ways repeatedly). [The modern 2.x docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#blank-lines) are probably a better resource, if not [the 3.x docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#blank-lines).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks! I edited the link to point to the more current docs.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter where you place the `#`

Either in the first identation level or close to the instruction, everything underneath it is going to be executed.

I suggest you to play with the code below and You'll figure it out yourself.

```
a = 1
b = 10
c = 100
d = 1000

if (a == 1):
    result = a+b
#   result = result + c
    result = result + d

    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python clearly considers comments when checking for indentation errors, which I hope the devs think of as a bug, and fix.  I was just running a program that failed to errors, but suddently worked when I deleted some of the comments (and changed nothing else).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32723883)